# Conditional format if cell is between percentage value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

i need to highlight row if a value falls into certain percentage value and so on.
B2 contains a percentage
A5:A9 has different percentage value
if any cell between A5;A9 falls under B2 entire row should highlight.

check the link below
[file link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ytjr-y2NnxKzEP5Lh69x-YpzEfYlgLA5qTgW3QR5xOo/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ytjr-y2NnxKzEP5Lh69x-YpzEfYlgLA5qTgW3QR5xOo/edit#gid=1279554896):

```
=$A5=xlookup($B$2,$A:$A,$A:$A,,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: worked Thanks a lot,

but can you explain $A:$A,$A:$A,,-1 this part

Comment: 1, this small [article](https://www.customguide.com/google-sheets/google-sheets-absolute-reference) here will explain clearly on absolute/relative cell references. 2, the xlookup `match_mode` factor with `-1` looks for an exact match or the next value that is lesser than the search_key(in your sample case its 50%)